# Spyder 5.4.3 load time is very long

Tags: spyder

I'm using Spyder 5.4.3 downloaded from anaconda.  It takes over 2 minutes to load.  Is that normal behavior or is there a way to make it load faster?

Comment: No it isn't normal behaviour.